# Getting Data from Service to Activity - Help!

Tags: android, service, android-intent

I have the service working now.  I'm just having trouble getting information back from the service to the main activity.

I have added a function to try and retrieve the data from the service which is launched after the button click in the main activity launches the service:

```
startService(passvars);
                //Init. variable for getDisplayInf() function to update the display with counter strings
                Running = 1;
                getDisplayInf();
```

And the getDisplayInf() ex:

```
public void getDisplayInf() {
        //Intent stIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        //Intent passvars = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Service.class);
        Bundle getvars = getIntent().getExtras();
        String Remaining;
        String CountDown;
        do {
            Remaining = getvars.getString("Remaining");
            CountDown = getvars.getString("CountDown");
            mRemaining.setText(Remaining);
            mCountDown.setText(CountDown);
            Running = getvars.getInt("Running");
        }
        while (Running == 1);
    };
```

The timer will set the Running variable to 0 on finish inside of the service.
As soon as I click the button with this new function in place it crashes the app, so I'm assuming it has to do with the Bundle/intent I'm using in the getDisplayInf() code.

In the service I'm doing this on the counter's onTick:

```
            @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Running = 1;
            Remaining = "Time Remaining:  ";
            CountDown = formatTime(millisUntilFinished);
            ticker();
        }
```

ticker's code:

```
public void ticker () {
         Intent passvars = new Intent(Service.this,MainActivity.class);
        //this is for the activity to keep looping to grab the countdown values while running this timer

        //now send it to the activity
        passvars.putExtra("Running", Running);
        //String Values to be passed to the activity

        //now send it to the activity
        passvars.putExtra("mRemaining", Remaining);


        //now send it to the activity
        passvars.putExtra("mCountDown", CountDown);
     };
```

Am I going about this in the right way?  Is there an easier way?  Some help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: how does it crash? what does logcat say?